# Using pyarmor in a django project with celery

Tags: django, celery, pyarmor

I'm using pyarmor to obfuscate my django project, following this steps:

```bash
pyarmor init --entry=manage.py
pyarmor build
```

Running the content in `dist/`, works fine.

But I would like running celery too.

It's possible? Do I need put it in `init` too?